# MetadataException [Unable to load the specified metadata resource]

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I really need help on this. There are a lot of information about the error in stackoverflow. However none of them is of help. A problem description is following in bottom of this question.

> **MetadataArtifactProcessing**
>   - this is set to "embed in output assembly", which is correct
>
> **app.config**
>   - I know the connectionstring have to be in the config file from the running
>   assembly. I've done this.
>
> **x86/x64 bit** I've doublechecked the compilations and framework versions
>   and everything is as it should be
>   (which in this case means .net 4 and
>   x86).
>
> **Path to res://*/Something.ssdl**
>  This is, perhaps, the most error-prone
>   option. I've tried locate the dll path
>   manually but only got very spooky
>   errors. Assembly not found or invalid
>   codebase or version. If I leave it a
>   star, it will seach the available
>   assemblies. However there are reports
>   saying that 3-tier applications must
>   *exactly* match (with printed assembly version and so on). Though, the
>   how-description are very unclear and
>   does not work either.
>
> **Name of resource**
>  .NET Reflector are used and I found the resources
>   names in (csdl, ssdl, msl) in the data class assembly. That name is exactly
>   corresponding to the config file. I have also tooked in mind that the resources get 
>   the name of the path and original filename (maph/maph/filename.edmx).
>
> **Name of the connectionstring**
>  The add name='' of the connectionstring
>   is exactly corresponding to the name
>   being searched for.

**Description**
This is a 3-tier application where edmx is located in Name.Data.dll. I created POCOS with Entity Poco generator built-in Visual Studio 2010. Moved the Pocos to the business layer (and yes, i fixed that path error which occurs when moving the pocos).

The very problem (as wroted in header) appears when I, in my third layer console test application, try asking the poco for data. I really hope you understand this isn't a "just a duplicate" and I'm in really need of conversation to fix this.

Thank's in advanced,

UPDATE:
Because it appears that this correspond to a false logic, I think the answers I search for is more of the type "how would i use EF in a presentaton - business - data" layered system?

Comment: What do you mean by moving POCOs to business layer? POCOs must be visible by Name.Data.dll. Also what do you mean by 3-tier application? Is it just layered application or are there real physical tiers?

Comment: 'Real' physical? Are you refering to that the third layer (console test app) will not have a reference direct to data.dll, just going through Name.Business.dll? I "moved" the POCO to Business because the generator has to be executed within the Entity designer (which relies in Data.dll).

Comment: Tier is used to describe physical boundary of a process. Still don't get your project structure. What is in data, what is in business and what dependencies these assemblies have? Where and how do you define context?

Comment: Data.dll, Business.dll, SomeApp.Exe/Webapp.dll. Webapp/SomeApp refers to Business.dll, which do validation, calculation, business object and such common tasks. Business.dll refers to Data.Dll which are a pure data container. It contains datasets which recieves data directly from sqlserver. I want Business.Dll to do all work against Data.Dll (like it is today, with the old DataSets). Webapp/Someapp should continue be completely free from Data.dll.

Comment: But if you want to use Entity framework 4 + POCOs your data layer must know that classes. So you can't place them to Data layer. It will result in circular reference between business and data.

Comment: Hm.. the POCO's are in Business.dll, EDMX are in Data.dll. Do you meant this isn't possible? If I ask business for a Poco class, the poco class knows it is in the Data.dll.

Comment: Show some code of accessing your data. How do you create `ObjectContext`, `ObjectSet` and how do you query data. What you describe should not even compile if configured correctly because `ObjectSet` initialization needs POCO class. The usual scenario uses separate assembly for POCOs and shares the assembly among all layers.

Comment: At this moment this is fully 100% autogenerated codes by wedmx designer and poco generator? Maybe I'm unclear, but the ObjectSet IS the Poco classes, aren't they? And they are in Business.dll. While Business.dll has a path to EDMX file in data.dll, which is referenced in Business.dll. I'm unsure with this techniq, May I ask how You would do this? Where do you locate pocos/edmx to separate the tiers? You may write next reply as a answer,

Comment: If you are using both EDMX designer (like code behind file) and POCO generator you have your classes generated twice - heavy entities in Data.dll and POCOs in Business.dll. That is not supposed result.

Comment: Finally, Ladislav! I'm glad to hear that. I feel this is far away from what should be done, but please - how do I work through business layer with the functionality that EF already delivers? IMHO EF is perfectly a business-object, but it don't correspond to the idea of having the data access in an own assembly..

Comment: EF is responsible for persisting business objects? Yes or no? If yes it obviously must have access to business objects code - either define it directly in Data.dll or in separate assembly shared among other assemblies.

Comment: Thank's. I feel as I'm back to beginning of my ideas :). Would you like to sum a little as an answer? It's a bit complicated to keep 100% answer rate when there are now answers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is directly related to your current exception but there is obviously some problem with your project structure.

If you want to use EF4 with POCO T4 template you must turn off default generator in Entity designer. POCO template can be placed in separate project but project defining entity model (and possibly derived ObjectContext) must have reference to this assembly.

Follow these tutorials to get introduction into using POCOs:

- [Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/21/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-1-the-experience.aspx)
- [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/28/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-2-complex-types-deferred-loading-and-explicit-loading.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an incorrect connection string in App.config file. You can try this:

```
Data Source=(IP address of DB);Initial Catalog=(DB name);Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```